# Trouble opening RData file - wrong data format?

Tags: r, rdata

I´m new to R.
I worked with R and saved my workspace Run3_Anova. When loading the workspace into R it does not work. I have checked the directory getwd() and set it with set(wd) according to the desired directory. I tried to load it in from the task menu (data/load workspace), the folder opens but the file (Run3_Anova) won´t show up. When I click on show all data formats, it becomes viewable.

Does that mean my data has the wrong format?

When I try the load function  `load("Run3_Anova.RData")`, I get:

```
Fehler in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : 
  kann Verbindung nicht öffnen
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  kann komprimierte Datei 'Data_Anova.RData' nicht öffnen. Grund evtl. 'No such file or directory'
```

I also tried the following:  `df <- load("Run3_Anova.RData")`
but I get the same error message as above

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you try including the full path? E.g. `load("C:/Order/Run3_Anova.RData")` Or drag and drop the file into the console?

Comment: Thank you. I tried the full pathload load("C:\\Users\\MyComputer\\Documents\\R\\Run3_Anova") and it does not work. I tried the drag and drop and it tells me: drag and drop only with .R, .Rdata and .rda files. So its the format?

Comment: The path that you gave is all wrong.  `MyComputer` should be above `Users`.  Maybe you just mistyped it.  I also think that this is a path problem.  Please try `load(file.choose())` and navigate to the file so that there is no question about the path.

Comment: hey, thank you. I think I just mistyped it here. When I add the full path (correctly) and press enter nothing happens in R.  I tried your suggestion load(file.choose()) I can select my file Run3_Anova but nothing appears in R. I tried it several times. I checked the file type and it just states file. Shouldn´t it say R Workspace?

Comment: What does `objects()` return after loading your `.RData` file?

Comment: Ok, after loading and objects(), R shows me: [1] "Data_Anova" "int"        "noint", which is correct. That´s what I did but I´m sorry I don´t know how to get to my analysis. If I print my data frame Data_Anova R shows me the raw data but not the analysis. I´m working with R Console and not R studio and haven´t downloaded any packages yet. Is that the problem?